# Replacing a portion of pattern with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying something very simple. The string I have is

```
Hello a1234 World a3456 Python a4567 a4567
```

I want to find all the words which

- start with a
- Have four numbers after it

I want to replace the small 'a' in such occurrences with a 'A'.

```
re.sub("\ba\d\d\d\d\b','A\d\d\d\d',str)
```

I know the above regex is wrong. I want the output as

```
Hello A1234 World A3456 Python A4567 A4567
```

How do I replace only a portion of the match I get?

**Edited with a fresh string**

```
str_check='''
Helloa1256
Hello a1256
Hello a1256
Hello a1256
'''
x=re.sub('\ba(?=\d\d\d\d\b)','A',str_check)
print(x)
```

Why is the the whole word search failing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re.sub(r'\ba(?=\d\d\d\d\b)','A',str)
```

Just use a `lookahead` as you just want to capture a single character and not the `4` digits after it.

Comment: Thanks! If use \b on a multiline string, this does not do a replace. But it works when  I remove \b.Any idea why? Also can you explain a bit about why \b is closed within the bracket and not outside?

Comment: @user567 `\b` is inside lookahead coz we say that find an `a` which has `4` digits after it and then a `\b`.So an `a` which has `5` digits after will not match.for the multiline string can you poast the string you trieed this on

Answer (score 1):

Use [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
re.sub(r'\ba(?=\d{4}\b)','A',string)
```

Assertions won't consume any characters but asserts whether a match is possible or not. So the above regex matches only the `a` which was followed by exactly 4 digits. Replacing the matched `a` with `A` will give you the desired output.

**OR**

[capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

```
re.sub(r'\ba(\d{4})\b',r'A\1',string)
```

This would capture the 4 digit number which follows the letter `a` into a group. Later we could refer the captured characters by specifying it's index number in the replacement part like `\1` (refers the first group).